# Error in FullCalendar: date.getFullYear is not a function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a line of content to each cell - which is basically the date of the cell - converted to the Hebrew date (which be displayed next to the regular date number)

I am using the standard [sample calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/demos/basic-views.html) to test with.

The code i am using is this:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
            var cellYear = date.getFullYear();
            var cellMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var cellDay = date.getDate();

            cell.prepend('<span class="hebDateInCell">' + ReturHebDate(cellDay,cellMonth,cellYear) + '</span>');
        },
       ....
```

which goes in after the `header` config.

and the error i get is:

```
date.getFullYear is not a function
```

I have verified that the `ReturHebDate` function works on the page.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/24x9e9g3/)**

Thanks!

Comment: Is `date` a Date object?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `console.log(date);`?

Comment: @A Worlff: Good question. My understanding is that its coming from fullCalendar - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/

Comment: @elbblick: `ReferenceError: date is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did you place the `console.log(date);` inside the dayRender function?

Comment: No, just ran it on the browser

Comment: Okay, please place it in the function (after `var cellDay = date,getDate();`) and run it, as we need the value of `date` within the scope of that function.

Comment: I placed it where you said, but it still stalled because of the above error. when i commented that whole section out, and placed the `console` line at the very start of the dayRender function - i get many lines exactly as follows: ` j { _isAMomentObject=true, _i="2014-09-12", _f="YYYY-MM-DD ", more...}`

Comment: We need those lines. Maybe paste them into a jsfiddle or add them to your question.

Comment: good idea, did just that - http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/24x9e9g3/1/

Comment: You need to use `date._d.getFullYear()`, date is a `Moment` object, or to simplify code, use e.g: `var dte = date._d;` then use `dte`, `var cellYear = dte.getFullYear();` etc... FYI, my nickname is A. Wolff, not A. Worlff ;)

Comment: I updated my answer, replacing getMonth and getDate should do the trick.

Comment: @A.Wolff - thanks - that seems to do the trick!  Pls add as an answer. 
Can you explain what the `_d.` adds to the date?

Comment: It basically accesses the date string inside the object. But as @A.Wolff pointed out below, you should try using the methods of the moment object. If this works though, roll with it ...

Comment: @kneidels `_d` is just a property of Moment object returning original Date object. As my comment in elbblick's answer suggests, you would have better i think to use Moment object methods instead, read the DOC coz sorry i don't know Moment library

Comment: Thanks guys. I would go with your recommendation - as i wont below the other answer,  the problem is that the other suggestion seems to return the wrong dates for the date cells, therefore the date conversion fails too.

Comment: I see now, why the other one wasn't working. You prepended every cell with "test", so returHebDate tried to return the Hebrew date for "test2014", "test8" and "test1", e.g. Remove the prepend line, and the solution below should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using

```
date.year(); // date in this case is a Moment object, see Moment.js documentation
```

instead of

```
date.getFullYear();
```

Edit: Also replace getMonth and getDate, so it will look someway like this:

```
var cellYear = date.year();
var cellMonth = date.month() + 1;
var cellDay = date.date();
```

Comment: I tries using the following syntax:
var cellYear = date.year();   var cellMonth = date.month()+1 ;   var cellDay = date.day();

which gave no error, but the dates that came out were all wrong and were all the4 same in each column (ie, all sundays) had the same value ...

Comment: +1 i think ya OP should use Moment object method instead of trying Date object methods

Comment: @elbblick - that doesnt work. see http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/vrugLmmo/ - all sundays have the same date, all mondays etc...

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an issue with the returHebDate function though, as I get all the dates, like here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrugLmmo/1/)

Comment: @elbblick - note that in your JsFiddle - the dates that are consoled are wrong. they start from `2014 7 0` whereas the calendar starts from `2014 8 31` - therefore the dates mismatch - they are wrong to begin with, even before the conversion.

Comment: Try again with my version, but remove the `cell.prepend('test');` That should work.

Comment: Thanks - did, but you should still see the dates are identical in the sunday column, monday column etc. see here a simplified model, http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/vrugLmmo/4/ - without the date conversion. note how in August 31 (the first day in the cal) - the `date()` that is prepended in, is actually July 0.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry. `day` is the day of the week, e.g. Monday is 0, Tuesday is 1 and so on. It should have been `date` instead. Also, fixed the month by re-adding the 1: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrugLmmo/5/) ... Please tell me it works now? =)